# "turn out" vs "turn out to be"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "turn out" and "turn out to be"? Can I use them interchangeably? If they mean exactly the same, is it better to stick to the shorter version without "to be"?

> Their project **turned out** highly profitable.

> Their project **turned out to be** highly profitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms mean exactly the same, but there's been [a significant usage shift](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turned%20out%20to%20be%20very%2Cturned%20out%20very&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) over the past couple of centuries...

[image]

...so unless you want to sound Victorian, you should normally include ***to be*** after ***turned out*** when used in this sense.

There's at least one major exception. It's [nearly always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turned%20out%20to%20be%20very%2Cturned%20out%20very&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) *turned out **well***, not ***...to be good***. There may be others, but I can't think of one just now, and I don't know if there's a way to collectively identify such exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. That's funny. As a rule, language tends to become simpler and shorter over time, but this expression has walked the opposite path.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I suspect contexts where we *don't* tend to include ***to be*** are primarily really simple ones - primarily of the form ***turned out [single-word-adjective]***. Note that the ***to be*** version is inherently far more suited to contexts with *longer* "adjectival phrases", so if you're only gonna use one form, that's the one to go for. Something might *turn out **to be not** a very good idea* (or *turn out **not to be** a very good idea*), but few people would want to say ***That turned out not a very good idea***.